# How to handle errors in client side (Android) from cloud functions (functions.https.HttpsError) using Typescript

Tags: java, android, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

First I'm use Typescript to write cloud functions to create an account with Firebase authentication. After creating new account, tried to add custom claims to the account and add the user info to the Firebase real-time database these steps complete successfully.

The problem appears when adding already existing account. The error prints in functions log but I cant throw it to Android

[My firebase cloud functions log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqlAs.jpg)

cloud functions code:.

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';
import { User } from './model/User';

admin.initializeApp();

const db = admin.database();

exports.createSellerAccount = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const userEmail = data.email;
  const userPassword = data.password;
  const user: User = new User();
  const newUserData = JSON.parse(data.newUser);

  user.setFirstName(newUserData.firstName);
  user.setLastName(newUserData.lastName);
  user.setMobileNumber(newUserData.mobileNumber);

  admin.auth().createUser({
    email: userEmail,
    password: userPassword
  }).then(function (userRecord) {
    // See the UserRecord reference doc for the contents of userRecord.
    const additionalClaims = {
      sellerAccount: true
    };

    admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(userRecord.uid, additionalClaims)
      .then(function (customToken) {
        // Send token back to client
        console.log("Successfully token created new user:", userRecord.uid);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("Error creating custom token:", error);
      });

    db.ref("Users/" + userRecord.uid).set(user)
      .then(() => {
        console.log("seller info inserted successfully");
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error while inserting seller info:", error);
      });

  }).catch(function(error) {
    // console.log("Error creating new user:", error);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('already-exists',error);
  });

})
```

Android code:.

```
private void createAccount() {
    ekhtarSeller.showProgressDialog(this);
    newUser.setFirstName(tietFirstName.getText().toString().trim());
    newUser.setLastName(tietLastName.getText().toString().trim());
    newUser.setMobileNumber(tietMobileNumber.getText().toString().trim());

    HashMap<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("email", tietEmail.getText().toString().trim());
    data.put("password", tietPassword.getText().toString().trim());
    data.put("newUser", new Gson().toJson(newUser));

    mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("createSellerAccount")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, String>() {
                @Override
                public String then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    ekhtarSeller.getProgressDialog().cancel();
                    String result = (String) task.getResult().getData();
                    Toast.makeText(CreateAccountActivity.this, result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return result;
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: Long story summarized: You're not dealing with promises at all correctly in this code.  With callable functions, you need to return a promise from the top-level of your function that resolves with the object you want to seriaize and send to the client, after all the async work is complete with the function.  You're kind of a long way off from that, given that you aren't returning a promise from the function at all, and you have other async work whose promises are not being factored into the final promise result.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson many thanks ,, the problem has solved after return  promise .

Answer (score 0):

It's happened you aren't using the values listed in a linked document in firebase for code parameter You get Error codes for Google APIs `"failed-auth"` or  `"invalid-email"`

Please visit 
[functions.https.HttpsError](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.https.HttpsError)

Comment: "already-exists" is the values listed in a linked document in firebase for code parameter